# Custom Endpoint API based on attribute gutenberg block

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, wordpress-gutenberg, wp-api

Viewed 4 times

0

I need to return all posts that have the value of a specific attribute that is saved in the custom block attributes gutenberg. This value in the query will be according to the endpoint below.

`http://idinheiro.local/wp-json/idinheiro/v1/blocks-posts/id-here-attribute-gutenberg-block`

below my callback function. In short, how do I look for this attribute and put it there in get_posts?

**Register routers**

```
public function register_routes() {
        $namespace = 'idinheiro/v1';
        $path = 'blocks-posts';

        register_rest_route( $namespace, '/' . $path . '/(?P<id>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)', [
            [
                'methods'             => 'GET',
                'callback'            => [$this, 'get_items'],
                'permission_callback' => [$this, 'get_items_permissions_check'],
            ],
        ]); 
    }
```

**Response data**

```
public function get_items($request) {
        $args = [
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            's' => 'cgb/block-idinheiro-blocks',
        ];

        $posts = get_posts($args);

        if (empty($posts)) {
            return new WP_Error( 'empty_post', 'there is no blocks inside on posts', [ 'status' => 404 ] );
        }

        $data = [];
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $data[$i]['id'] = $request['id'];
            $data[$i]['post_id'] = $post->ID;
            $data[$i]['post_name'] = $post->post_title;
            $data[$i]['post_url'] = get_permalink($post->ID);
            $i++;
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return new WP_REST_Response($data, 200);
    }
```

I thought of something that went something like this. Or if you have another solution on how to get this, I'll be grateful

```
$args = [
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            's' => 'cgb/block-idinheiro-blocks',
            'value_attribute_my_block' = $request['id']
        ];

        $posts = get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code provided, here is a potential solution that may solve your issue:

In your custom block `cgb/block-idinheiro-blocks`, you could set the `value_attribute_my_block` attribute source as [meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#common-sources) if the block is only used once per a post/page ([multiple](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/#multiple) can be restricted in the attributes - the default is true, set to **false**). NB. your meta field must be registered with [register_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/) in php/your main plugin file or the value won't save.

Storing the value as `post_meta` enables you to use the powerful meta query to retrieve posts into your function `get_items()` easily. This strategy avoids having to parse the content of the post, as by default on save block attributes are serialized. In your current query `$args`, your `'s'` parameter would find posts with the block but would still have to parse the value of the attribute, which would be an alternative but likely not as fast/performant as meta query would be.